# Как дублировать блок кода при клике

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(".room-guests-count").click(function(e){
 $(".form-open").toggle();
 e.stopPropagation();
});
$('.form-open').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function() {
  $('.form-open').hide();
});
//код которое должен добавить дубликат блока 
$("#add-room").on("click", function(){
//Получаем имя и комментарий из инпутов
 var adultsChildren = $(".adults-children-wrapper");
 //Добавляем результат к нужному блоку
 $('.adults-children').add("<div class='adults-children-wrapper'></div>");
});
```

```css
body {
  background:lightblue;
}
/*ROOM GUESTS COUNT*/
.room-guests-count {
 width: 34%;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-right: 4%;
 background: #fff;
 height: 66px;
 margin-right: 152px;
}
.form-open {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 top: 83px;
 background-color: #fff;
 height: auto;
 left: 9px;
 width: 348px;
}

.form-open:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 right: 300px;
 bottom: 93px;
}
.room-guests-content {
 padding-top: 23px;
 padding-left: 15px;
}
.click_hidden_text {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 left: 163px;
 top: 73px;
 opacity: 0.8;
}
.form-search {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
 
}
.form-item {
 padding: 10px 5px;
 clear: both;
 height: 14px;
}
.edit-rooms {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 float: left;
 color: #000;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
.rooms-guests-plus {
 float: right;
 color: #fff;
 background:#ccc;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 24px;
 top: -6px;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 18px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.form-text {
 text-align: center;
 width: 6%;
 width: 20px !important;
 text-decoration: center;
 float: right;
 border:0;
 padding: 0;
 height: auto;
 outline: 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.textfield label {
 margin-right: 2.5px;
 display: inline;
 font-size: 13px;
}
.children-1 label {
 display: inline;
 font-size: 13px;
}
.rooms-guests-minus {
 float: right;
 color: #fff;
 background:#e7e7e7;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 24px;
 top: -6px;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 18px;
 cursor:auto;
}
.adults-children {
 clear: both;
}
.rooms-id {
 line-height: 40px;
 float: left;
 padding:5px 0 0 15px;
 color: #000;
}
.already-min {
 float: right;
 margin: -16px 0px 2px 6px;
 padding: 0;
 background: #fff;
}
.already-min-search {
 float: right;
 margin: 5px 10px 5px 2px;
}
.adults-children-wrapper {
 clear: both;
}
.children-1 {
 padding: 10px 5px;
 clear: both;
 height: 14px;
}
.edit-children {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 float: left;
 color: #000;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
.textfield {
 clear: both;
 height: 14px;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="room-guests-count">
  <div class="room-guests-content">
    Взрослых
    <span class="ga-count">2</span>
    , Детей 
    <span class="children-count">0</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-open">
  <div class="form-search">
    <div class="form-item">
      <label class="edit-rooms">Количество номеров</label>
      <div class="rooms-guests-plus" id="add-room">+</div>
      <input type="text" name="rooms" max="9" min="1" maxlength="128" class="form-text" value="1" size="60" readonly="readonly">
      <div class="rooms-guests-minus">-</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="adults-children">
  <div class="adults-children-wrapper">
    <div class="rooms-id">Номер 1:</div>
    <div class="already-min-search">
      <div class="children-1">
        <label for="edit-children">Детей</label>
        <div class="rooms-guests-plus">+</div>
        <input type="text" name="childrenqt" value="0" max="5" min="0" maxlength="5" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
        <div class="rooms-guests-minus">-</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="already-min">
      <div class="textfield">
        <label for="edit">Взрослых</label>
        <div class="rooms-guests-plus">+</div>
        <input type="text" name="edit" value="2" max="10" min="0" maxlength="5" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
        <div class="rooms-guests-minus">-</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Всем привет.Есть задачка которое при клике на кнопку плюс добавил дубликат существующего блока.И при клике минус удалил его.Окончательный резултат как должно быть на картинке показано.Больше 9 блоков добавить нельзя.[Изображения 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwzcR.jpg) [image: изображения 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пробуем так (использовал синтаксис ES6, но не думаю, что будет сложно разобраться):

```js
const room = document.querySelector('.room-guests-count');
const form = document.querySelector('.form-open');
const adultsChildren = document.querySelector('.adults-children');
const adultsChildrenWrapper = document.querySelector('.adults-children-wrapper');

let formIsOpened = false;

room.onclick = () => {
 if(!formIsOpened) {
  form.style.display = 'block'
 } else {
  form.style.display = 'none'
 }
 formIsOpened = !formIsOpened;
}
const toggleRoom = () => {
 const addRoomButton = document.querySelector('#add-room');
 const removeRoomButton = document.querySelector('#remove-room');
 const countRoom = document.querySelector('.form-text');
 
 const addSection = () => {
  const wrapper = document.createElement("div");
  wrapper.className = "adults-children-wrapper";
  const template = adultsChildrenWrapper.innerHTML;
  wrapper.innerHTML = adultsChildrenWrapper.innerHTML;                   
  adultsChildren.appendChild(wrapper);  
 }
 const removeSection = () => {
  adultsChildren.lastChild.remove();
 }
 
 addRoomButton.onclick = () => {
  if(countRoom.value == 9) return;
  countRoom.value++;
  addSection();
  
 }
 removeRoomButton.onclick = () => {
  if(countRoom.value == 1) return;
  countRoom.value--;
  removeSection();
 }
 
}
toggleRoom();
```

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}

/*ROOM GUESTS COUNT*/
.room-guests-count {
  width: 34%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 4%;
  background: #fff;
  height: 66px;
  margin-right: 152px;
}

.form-open {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 83px;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: auto;
  left: 9px;
  width: 348px;
}

.form-open:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  right: 300px;
  bottom: 93px;
}

.room-guests-content {
  padding-top: 23px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.click_hidden_text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 163px;
  top: 73px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.form-search {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
}

.form-item {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  clear: both;
  height: 14px;
}

.edit-rooms {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  float: left;
  color: #000;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.rooms-guests-plus {
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 24px;
  top: -6px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-text {
  text-align: center;
  width: 6%;
  width: 20px !important;
  -webkit-text-decoration: center;
          text-decoration: center;
  float: right;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.textfield label {
  margin-right: 2.5px;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.children-1 label {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.rooms-guests-minus {
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 24px;
  top: -6px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.adults-children {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.rooms-id {
  line-height: 40px;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 0 0 15px;
  color: #000;
}

.already-min {
  float: right;
  margin: -16px 0px 2px 6px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

.already-min-search {
  float: right;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 2px;
}

.adults-children-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.children-1 {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  clear: both;
  height: 14px;
}

.edit-children {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  float: left;
  color: #000;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.textfield {
  clear: both;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="room-guests-count">
  <div class="room-guests-content">
    Взрослых
    <span class="ga-count">2</span>
    , Детей 
    <span class="children-count">0</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-open">
  <div class="form-search">
    <div class="form-item">
      <label class="edit-rooms">Количество номеров</label>
      <div class="rooms-guests-plus" id="add-room">+</div>
      <input type="text" name="rooms" max="9" min="1" maxlength="128" class="form-text" value="1" size="60" readonly="readonly">
      <div class="rooms-guests-minus" id="remove-room">-</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="adults-children">
  <div class="adults-children-wrapper">
    <div class="rooms-id">Номер 1:</div>
    <div class="already-min-search">
      <div class="children-1">
        <label for="edit-children">Детей</label>
        <div class="rooms-guests-plus">+</div>
        <input type="text" name="childrenqt" value="0" max="5" min="0" maxlength="5" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
        <div class="rooms-guests-minus">-</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="already-min">
      <div class="textfield">
        <label for="edit">Взрослых</label>
        <div class="rooms-guests-plus">+</div>
        <input type="text" name="edit" value="2" max="10" min="0" maxlength="5" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
        <div class="rooms-guests-minus">-</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Из пожеланий: 
Нужно разобраться с версткой (float, добавление классов к активным/неактивным кнопкам).

Comment: а что там такого в верстке что нужно разобратся @NeedHate ?

Comment: ну я бы float  не использовал, шаблонизатор "клонируемой" секции я бы вставлял через шаблонные строки (это позволит, например, иметь дефолтное значение инпутов, потому как если в "клонируемом" элементе значение инпутов будет изменяться, то "новые секции" будут с клонированными значениями), "номер 1" будет увеличиваться, например, на 1, при добавлении. Ну и куча нюансов, которые всплывут позже )

Comment: буду рад если добавите еще ответ со всеми изменениями которым нужно сделать,но пожалуйста не изменяте текущий ответ.

Comment: у вас лишняя переменная или мне так кажется ? const template @NeedHate

Comment: верно, лишняя... должна была стать тут: wrapper.innerHTML = adultsChildrenWrapper.innerHTML; можно удалять.